# One R GUI for multiple vim R script in Linux

Tags: linux, r, vim-plugin

I installed vim-r-plugin on my Linux computer. There is one problem is when I was editing multiple R files and each one will launch an R program by using `\rt`. I am wondering how to just launch one R window for multiple R code files.

Comment: Are you wedded to vim? Rstudio works in Linux too, as does RStudio server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is if you open your other R scripts as buffers within your original vim session. Using `\aa` or similar will run the script in the active buffer in the R window.

In case you don't know how to do this, use `:e filename` in vim to start editing a different script. You can also split the screen or have tabs. Look up vim buffers on the Wikia for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot; only one file can be connected to the R session. I can't find the specific explanation right now, but it should be in the help file.